# Azure ASP.NET RC1 Deployment Failure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core RC1 application that is deployed to Azure via GitHub deployment (i.e., I commit source to GitHub and the application is built/deployed by Azure).

Everything worked fine up until sometime within the last 5 days.  I successfully deployed my application 5 days ago (~2016-05-16).  Today I made a change and tried to deploy again but the deploy failed.  I attempted to deploy again (thinking the problem may be transient) and encountered the same problem.  I then tried re-deploying the previous known good commit, which failed again (note: `project.lock` is in source control).  I then rolled master back to the previous known good and pushed which triggered another deploy, same error.

It could be just a coincidence, but RC2 with significant breaking changes was released since I previously attempted a deploy.

Looking at my deployment log, the first error is:

```
Failed to resolve conflicts for DNX,Version=v4.5.1

Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration':
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet 1.0.0-rc1-update4),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final),
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) (via package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.0.0-rc1-final)"
```

I get a whole slew of errors like that (`Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for ...`) for various transitive dependencies.

Since this project successfully deployed 5 days ago with a particular commit/`project.lock`, I have to assume something has changed in Azure or NuGet to cause this.

I deleted my local NuGet package cache and was able to successfully rebuild in Visual Studio and VSCode.

Any advice on troubleshooting steps is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened when RC2 was released, which caused an issue with the RC1 deployments. Please use the following workaround (from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9840ce88-6479-46b2-a312-7ac6a41366a4/rc1-web-site-cant-be-updated-anymore?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)):

- Copy .deployment and deploy.cmd from https://github.com/davidebbo-test/AspNet5RC1
- Edit [this line](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/AspNet5RC1/blob/0e42059b5a9938ea9605542b88199f740baec55c/deploy.cmd#L96) in deploy.cmd to point to your project.json
- Also if your project is on something other than `rc1-update1` (e.g. if it's on `beta8`), you'll need to fix up all the rc1 references in that file (there are two).
- Commit both files at the root of your repository.

That being said, you should be looking into moving to RC2 :)

Comment: I'll try these steps this evening.  I can't move to RC2 until Swashbuckle is updated to be RC2 compatible, that is my last un-migrated dependency.

Comment: Understood. The workaround will get you going again until the time for RC2 is right.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I'm running into this issue, but I was already using a custom deployment model (to auto-run my EF migrations). I'm getting a slightly different error about an attempt to download RC2 libraries. Comparing your script to mine, the only difference is the use of x64, my EF command, and the removal of the POST_DEPLOY detection. Do you think any of those would play a factor?

Comment: @Dillie-O Can you open issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues with error details? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to check is if you have any "open" library version requirements. For me, the issue at hand was with my 1.0.0-* dependencies. Since they were "open" on the version, they were attempting to grab rc2 dependencies which were incompatible. Once I changed these to a fixed RC1, things resolved themselves. I was unable to update to RC2 because some of my other libraries were incompatible.