# Azure web application suddenly gives 500 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

My web application in azure is suddenly giving me 500 errors and I can't find any reason for it. I can't even request an image using a direct link.

500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

The ASP.net web application runs perfectly on my local machine and the app used to work just perfectly a week ago. Since then I haven't made much changes to the application.

I even tried to upload the ASP.net application to a new web application instance, and still the same problem. How can it work locally and not remotely? And how can I debug this? I can't run a remote debugger since it never start the application. It just times out..

It's an ASP.NET 5, angular 2 application using typescript btw.

My **eventlog.xml** says this:

> 100000Keywords636333796ApplicationRD00155D4A13C6Process '42576' failed to start. Port = 18693, Error Code =
>   '-2147023829'.100000Keywords637631703ApplicationRD00155D4A13C6Process '50976' failed to start. Port = 22932, Error Code =
>   '-2147023829'.100000Keywords639938953ApplicationRD00155D4A13C6Process '49572' failed to start. Port = 4513, Error Code =
>   '-2147023829'.

Comment: Error Code = '-2147023829'. Ah yes.. thank you Microsoft that is very helpful.

Comment: That's quite [useful](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1147).

Comment: By ASP.NET 5, do you mean the old RC1? Also, how are you deploying it to Azure? Using it or from VS?

Comment: DNX SDK: 1.0.0-rc1-update2, and I publish via VS yes.

Comment: There is a known issue, but it only affects git deployments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381377/azure-asp-net-rc1-deployment-failure/37381832#37381832. So yours is likely different. Can you share the name of the web app where you tried deploying a new instance?

Comment: It's here: http://fotballem.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: It only leads to a nice: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Comment: If you look through your stdout logs in d:\home\LogFiles, there is a more explicit error there: `Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web, ef.`. Looks similar to what's discussed on https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/629, so I'd take it with those guys.

Comment: Of course, the most right thing to do is to move to RC2, as RC1 is no longer supported.

Comment: use this kudu and send all detail log on post : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: After converting -2147023829 to hex, it is 8007042B. Search this particular error code might be helpful.

Comment: I would take the issue up to your network host first of all and explain to them that this application works perfectly fine on your own machine. It could be a server issue.

Answer (score 1):

See this article for remote debugging tips on Azure Web Sites.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/

The first step I'd take is displaying custom errors on failure. To do this, you need to update the web.config (Either in Azure, or in Visual Studio)

```
    3.) Add the following line to the system.web element:
        <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```